# Why does store() in AssemblyScript not store data at the specified pointer?

Tags: webassembly, assemblyscript

I have some assemblyScript code:

```js
export function run(): void {
  store<string>(0, 'hello, my name is marty');
}
```

That stores a string at pointer `0` in memory.

However, the produced .wat file stores the string at location `1056` instead of `0`:

```
(module
 (type $none_=>_none (func))
 (memory $0 1)
 (data (i32.const 1036) "L")
 (data (i32.const 1048) "\01\00\00\00.\00\00\00h\00e\00l\00l\00o\00,\00 \00m\00y\00 \00n\00a\00m\00e\00 \00i\00s\00 \00m\00a\00r\00t\00y")
 (export "run" (func $assembly/index/run))
 (export "memory" (memory $0))
 (func $assembly/index/run
  i32.const 0
  i32.const 1056
  i32.store
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It stores pointer of string with value `1056` into zero (`0`) index in linear memory. So everything correct.